# procedimientos almacenados

Tags: sql-server

Necesito saber como hacer procedimientos almacenados en SQL Server
para el  trabajar tengo una base de datos pequeña algo así:

```
use Inventario
create table Clientes (
Nit int,
Nombre char (50),
Direccion char(50),
Telefono int,
primary key (Nit)
);

create table Representante_de_ventas (
Id_vdor int,
Nombre char (50),
Cuota_Vtas int,
primary key (Id_vdor)
);

create table Productos (
Id int,
Descripcion char (50),
Precio int,
primary key (Id)
);

create table Pedido (
Num_pedido int,
Vdor int,
Nit_cliente int,
Fecha_pedido date,
Producto int,
Cantidad int,
primary key (Num_pedido,Nit_cliente,Vdor,Producto),
foreign key (Nit_cliente) references Clientes(Nit),
foreign key (Vdor) references Representante_de_ventas(Id_vdor),
foreign key (Producto) references Productos(Id),
);
```

Comment: Trata de especificar que es lo que quieres que haga tu procedimiento

Answer (score 2):

Para crear un procedimiento almacenado debes posicionarte en la BD en la cual quieras generar el procedimiento y ahí hacer lo siguiente:

1.- Abres la base de datos presionando el signo "+"

2.- Vas a la carpeta que se llama Programmability y presionas de nuevo el "+"

3.- Te posicionas en la carpeta Stored Procedures y presionas click derecho

4.- Una vez presionado click derecho seleccionas la opción Stored Procedure...

5.- Una vez realizado el paso anterior aparecerá el cuerpo del Procedimiento almacenado de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <Nombre_del_procedimiento>
-- Declara los parametros aquí
@Parametro1 int
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Inserta el Query aquí
    SELECT 
       Ejemplo
    FROM
       Tabla_Ejemplo
    WHERE
       Ejemplo = @Parametro1
END
GO
```

6.- Presionas Ejecutar o (F5) para guardar el Query

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que seguir una estructura y mantener un orden, ayudaria mucho saber que quieres realizar con tu procedimiento almacenado.

Por ejemplo uno que consulte el los pedidos de un determinado cliente, pero solo el numero de pedido, fecha y el nombre del cliente, sería asi:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPR_OBTENERPEDIDOXCLIENTE
 @NIT_CLIENTE INT

AS  
BEGIN  

SELECT
P.NUM_PEDIDO,
P.FECHA_PEDIDO,
C.CLIENTE

FROM PEDIDO P
INNER JOIN CLIENTE C ON C.NIT = P.NIT_CLIENTE
WHERE P.NIT_CLIENTE = @NIT_CLIENTE

END
```